# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I have  python 2.7 and i have installed Tensorflow 0.8.0. It was working fine formonths. I installed sklearn today and after that when i call Tensorflow python closes with this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

currently Tensorflow 0.8.0 has an issue .
You have to import numpy first then Tensorflow then the problem is resolved.
Although in starting I was able to call Tensorflow alone but now I have to call numpy to resolve the problem.

Comment: Do you also have a link you could post to give deeper information, examples, related problems, etc.?